# Fortran solver for the Sparse LSE problem

Tags: sparse-matrix, fortran, constrained-optimization, least-squares

I was wondering if there is a Fortran library that contains a solver for the Sparse LSE(linear equality-constrained least squares) problem
$$
min_{x}\|Cx-d\|^2  \text{ subject to }   Ax=b
$$
where $A$ and $C$ are large and sparse.

For dense linear systems, LAPACK has the subroutine [DGGLSE](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/d85/dgglse_8f.html#a1f03c8580ac1aaafb0f092fad4377d16), but I am looking for a solver for sparse systems.